# Spring Boot replicate embedded servlet customizer to management port

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a custom `WebServerFactoryCustomizer` but its not available for management port. What's the best way to make the customization available to server on management port? The regular server is on port =8080 and management server is on port = 8082.

I tried playing around with `ServletManagementWebServerFactoryCustomizer` but it didn't work. Any pointers will be appreciated.

here is the customizer (to disable TRACE for Undertow)

```
public class UndertowCustomizer implements
  WebServerFactoryCustomizer<ConfigurableUndertowWebServerFactory> {

@Override
public void customize(final ConfigurableUndertowWebServerFactory undertowWebServerFactory) {
  undertowWebServerFactory.addDeploymentInfoCustomizers(deploymentInfo ->
      deploymentInfo.addInitialHandlerChainWrapper(handler ->
          new DisallowedMethodsHandler(handler, HttpString.tryFromString(HttpMethod.TRACE.name())))
  );
 }
}
```

A sample reproducible service is at https://github.com/ranarula/WebServerCustomizer

Answer (score 0):

Indeed I feel lack of information regarding this topic as well but I was able to get it working by following the documentation [Adding custom endpoints](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.x/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html#production-ready-customizing-endpoints-programmatically)

what you can do is just put the customizer in ***spring.factories***

```
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.web.ManagementContextConfiguration=UndertowCustomizer
```

javadocs of this class might be helpful as well [ManagementContextConfiguration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/web/ManagementContextConfiguration.html)